# How would I use Walker to modify wp_list_pages to display thumbnail only at lowest level in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, hierarchy

I'm working on a writer's site. The pages are structured like so:

```
All Books
   Series
     Series A
        Book 1, Book 2, etc.
      Series B
        Book 1, Book 2, etc.
   Stand-alone novels
      Book 1, Book 2, etc.
```

Each book has its own page.

I can use wp_list_pages to generate lists of links at whatever level I want. What I need to do is use Walker classes to customize wp_list_pages [like this](http://badfunproductions.com/create-a-custom-walker-class-to-extend-wp_list_pages/), but so that *only* the lowest Book level uses the Featured Image (=book cover) for the link.

How do I do this? That is, how do I put in images *only* on the lowest level, which is not the same number of steps down from the top in different parts of the tree?

Answer (score 0):

Check if page has children:

```
class Thumbnail_walker extends Walker_page {
    function start_el(&$output, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page) {
        if ( $depth )
            $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        else
            $indent = '';

        extract($args, EXTR_SKIP);
        $css_class = array('page_item', 'page-item-'.$page->ID);
        if ( !empty($current_page) ) {
            $_current_page = get_page( $current_page );
            _get_post_ancestors($_current_page);
            if ( isset($_current_page->ancestors) && in_array($page->ID, (array) $_current_page->ancestors) )
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_ancestor';
            if ( $page->ID == $current_page )
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_item';
            elseif ( $_current_page && $page->ID == $_current_page->post_parent )
                $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        } elseif ( $page->ID == get_option('page_for_posts') ) {
            $css_class[] = 'current_page_parent';
        }

        $css_class = implode( ' ', apply_filters( 'page_css_class', $css_class, $page, $depth, $args, $current_page ) );

        $children = get_children( 'post_type=page&numberposts=1&post_parent=' . $page->ID );
        if ( empty($children) ) {
            $link_contents = $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', '' ) . $link_after . get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, array(72,72));
        }
        else {
            $link_contents = $link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $page->post_title, $page->ID ) . $link_after;
        }
        $output .= $indent . '<li class="' . $css_class . '"><a href="' . get_permalink($page->ID) . '">' . $link_contents .'</a>';

        if ( !empty($show_date) ) {
            if ( 'modified' == $show_date )
                $time = $page->post_modified;
            else
                $time = $page->post_date;

            $output .= " " . mysql2date($date_format, $time);
        }
    }
}
```